# Angular2 AoT Compilation Error: createAotCompiler is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I am trying to do AoT compilation on a very basic app, and I am getting this error in windows, Am I missing any package as I haven't used angular-cli to start

```
> TypeError: compiler.createAotCompiler is not a function
>         at Function.CodeGenerator.create (...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:78:36)
```

**Node Version: 5.2.0**

**Packages**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^3.2.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.2.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.1.15",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.48",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.34",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10"
  }
```

Comment: no help to you, but this is not limited to windows, I'm getting the same with linux, and  I did use angular-cli to start

Answer (score 2):

I think you are encountering this because of version mismatch between angular modules inter-dependencies.

The top part of your dependencies should be like this to match with version 2.2.2 of the compiler-cli.

```
"@angular/common": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/core": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/forms": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/http": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/platform-server": "^2.2.2",
"@angular/router": "^3.2.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "^2.2.2",
```

Comment: this fixed it for me